# Generating Canonical Url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, canonical-link

I want to generate Canonical url´s at my ASP.NET MVC project. I did a simple test and worked, but is it right? Can I have some problems? I see some examples much more complicated, mine seems too good to be truth

I am just doing this:

```
public string CanonicalUrl()
{
    RouteValueDictionary valores = new RouteValueDictionary(ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> keyValuePair in ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState)
    {
        valores[keyValuePair.Key] = keyValuePair.Value.Value.AttemptedValue;
    }

    return Url.RouteUrl(null, valores, Request.Url.Scheme, null);
}
```

I am using it now. Until now I didn´t have any problem:

http://blog.fujiy.net/?page=5

http://blog.fujiy.net/?tag=%2Fjavascript&page=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked

```
public string CanonicalUrl()
{
    RouteValueDictionary valores = new RouteValueDictionary(ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> keyValuePair in ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState)
    {
        valores[keyValuePair.Key] = keyValuePair.Value.Value.AttemptedValue;
    }

    return Url.RouteUrl(null, valores, Request.Url.Scheme, null);
}
```

Comment: Before assigning the value, you should check that they key is not empty. If the model state has an error that doesn't apply to a specific property, an empty string key is added.

Comment: I should clarify that the empty key isn't the problem, it's that the model state will have a null value for states with an empty key.